# How to let the user select a specific column and row in mysql database using c# to retrieve data?

Tags: c#, mysql

In this code I am attempting to access a cell in a mysql table (named: timeslots2) where by the user selects the column and the program selects the row. The Table looks as follows:

```
Day      |    11am    |    12pm
----------------------------------
Monday         2             3
Tuesday        3             2
Wednesday      1             3
etc.
```

i.e. The User selects "11am", the program detects the current day (example: monday), and then the program returns "2".

This is what I have so far, however I'm stumped on what I should write to incorporate the users input.

```
private void select_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string today = (System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString());

      string constring = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root2;password=root";   
      string Query2 = "select * from database.timeslots2 where day= '" + today + "';";
      MySqlConnection conDataBase2 = new MySqlConnection(constring);
      MySqlCommand cmdDataBase2 = new MySqlCommand(Query2, conDataBase2);

         conDataBase2.Open();
     }
```

I should also mention that there is a string named "shiftLunch" that holds the user's input for the specific column they chose (i.e. 11am, 12pm, etc.). Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand if you ask to explain how to execute and read the values from your query or if you are just asking on how to make your query return just the column choosen by the user.

Comment: I dont know what code to write to bring the mySQL variable into c# to be used.

Comment: I dont want the whole column just the single cell as determined by the user

Comment: Now, how does the user select the column? Do you have a textbox or something to get the user input? These informations are important to let the community answer your question

Comment: sorry yes its a prepopulated combo box:

    shiftLunch = lunchTimes.Text;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your column names stored in a combobox pay attention to set the DropDownStyle to DropDownList. This is absolutely necessary to block any attempt to write a custom text in the combobox. Column names cannot be parameterized and you shouldn't allow your users to type them because you could be hacked with an sql injection method

So, if you have correctly set the column names in your combo, then your code could be written in this way

```
private void select_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string today = (System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString());
  string colName = lunchTimes.Text;

  string constring = "......";
  string Query2 = "select " + colName + " from database.timeslots2 " + 
                  "where day= @day";
  using(MySqlConnection conDataBase2 = new MySqlConnection(constring))
  using(MySqlCommand cmdDataBase2 = new MySqlCommand(Query2, conDataBase2))
  {
     conDataBase2.Open();
     cmdDataBase2.Parameters.Add("@day", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = today;
     using(MySqlDataReader reader = cmdDataBase2.ExecuteReader())
     {
         while(reader.Read())
             Console.WriteLine(today + " value is " + reader[0].ToString());
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: the only problem is that the number that gets returned need to be associated with a variable in c# so a calculation can be done with it. PS this is a windows application.

Comment: @Paul I have used the Console.WriteLine just for demonstration purpose not because this is a Console application. To set a variable you need to convert the returned value to the datatype of the variable I.E. _int number = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);_